# High Cohesion: HotelBean, CarBean and HotelCarBean - UML2 and the UP

Tags: uml, software-design

Let's look at the example from the book [UML 2 and the Unified Process: Practical Object-Oriented Analysis and Design (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321321278)

[image]

My question is: where to put the responsability of "selling a package of hotel room plus car hire"? How to model such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a question of modeling and naming. You might imagine a class SellerBean wich exposes the appropriate methods for selling packages of elements to hire. The way the information about the HotelBean and CarBean hired are encapsulated depend of what you want to model. You could add a HireBean class (or PackageBean, as you wish). Here is a proposition:

[image]